# How to build Aggregations on Apache Solr with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, solr

I have a requirement to build aggregations on the data that we receive to our Apache Kafka...

I am little bit lost which technlogical path to follow...

It seems people see the standard way, a constellation of Apache Kafka <-> Apache Spark <-> Solr

[Bitnami Data Platform](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/dataplatform-bp1)

I can't find concrete examples how this actually functions, but I am also asking myself would any solution von

Apache Kafka <-> Kafka Connect Solr <-> Solr

would not do the trick becasue solr supports aggregations also...

[Solr Aggregation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/search-sample.html)

but I saw some code snippets that aggregate the Data in Spark and write under special index to Solr.....

Also probably aggregation mit Kafka <-> Kafka Connect Solr <-> Solr will only function for only one Topic from Kafka, so if I have to combine the data from 2 or more, different Topics and aggregate, then Kafka, Spark, Solr is way to go.... (or this viable at all)

So as you may read, I am little bit confused, so I like to ask here, how are you approching this problem with your real life solutions....

Thx for answers...

Answer (score 0):

Spark can of course join multiple topics. So can Flink, or Kafka Streams/KsqlDB. Spark or Flink just happen to be able to also write their data to external sources, such as Solr, rather than exclusively back into a new Kafka topic. The "downside" is that you need to maintain a scheduler exclusively for those, as compared to running a cluster of standalone Kafka Connect or Kafka Streams JAR applications. If you're using kubernetes, then that could be used for all of above (maybe not Flink... Haven't tried)

Kafka Connect can consume multiple topics and, depending on the connector configuration, might write to one or many Solr collections.

Comment: First thx for answer, but you are a bringing more options to the table and adding more to the confusion :). So I interpret like this, if I have an existing Spark Cluster it would male sense to use Kafka <-> Spark <-> Solr, otherwhise if I want mutltiple output Datasources Flink would make sense instead of Spark and if I want to stay in the realm of Kafka and produce only to Kafka, any combination of KStream, Kafka Connect would make more sense....

Comment: Spark can also write to multiple destinations, but, yes, that's how I see it